# How to debug or print in Flutter web?

Tags: debugging, flutter, flutter-web

I'm using `Flutter 1.10.15` and `Android Studio 3.5.1` for  Flutter Web development and my big! problem is I can't debug and even I can't print something in console because only a white page is displayed in `chrome` when I press "run" or "debug" button in toolbar.

The only way I can run project is in web-server mode with following command and showing variable values and exceptions in `AlertDialog` popup!:

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname=192.168.50.147 --web-port=5624 --local-engine=host_debug_unopt --profile -v lib\pages\splash.dart
```

Can anyone tell me a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could finally find that `Google Chrome DevTools` feature has a "Console" section that shows all prints written in `Flutter Web`'s dart code when running project in `Web-Server` mode. 
This is while in `Web-Server` mode, non of prints are shown in Android Studio console.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using VSCode, open **launch.json** inside **.vscode** folder and add the following args:

```
"--web-port=5000"
"--web-enable-expression-evaluation"
```

Here is an example of a complete **launch.json** file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "web",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--web-port=5000",
                "--web-enable-expression-evaluation"
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

With this configuration, you can start debugging your Flutter web apps in VSCode, using breakpoints.

Comment: had to add "deviceId": "chrome" in configurations to get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
Flutter Channel beta, 1.18.0-11.1.pre
```

You can print in the console and also debug in Android Studio and Chrome at the same time.

- In order to do so, you need to select Chrome (web) from the dropdown. Web Server (web) doesn't work for me.

[image: Targer device]

- Hit the Debug button and wait the for the new window to be opened.
- Put the breakpoint in AS, not in Chrome.

[image: Breakpoint]

- Open Chrome's Developer tools.
- Hit the plus button or whatever to hit your breatpoint.
- Inspect the Dart code in Chrome.

[image: Chrome's Developer tools]

And btw, `print` prints in both Chrome's and AS's consoles.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible right now, Flutter Web is still in Tech-Preview version, not even Beta.
You can expect some updates about this feature till end of November: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1773

Comment: When I started the project and there were only a few pages it was OK and at least printing worked well in run on Chrome mode, but I don't know why now none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging on Android studio for web works for **Flutter beta v1.17.0** and newer

For older versions use: Flutter beta v1.14.6

If it still does not work, maybe run `flutter clean`

Upgrade: dart, flutter plugins in android studio

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem.

- Close your project and reopen.
- when run , connect system to internet.